# System of bilinear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-product

Given constants $n$ and $\ell$, where $\ell < n$, suppose we have the following set of equations in column vectors $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in {\mathbb{C}^{\ell}}$

$$\begin{array}{rl}  
  \langle a_1, a_n \rangle &= 0\\  
  \langle a_1, a_{n-1} \rangle + \langle a_2, a_n \rangle &= 0\\  
  \langle a_1, a_{n-2} \rangle + \langle a_2, a_{n-1} \rangle + \langle a_3, a_{n}\rangle &= 0\\
  &\vdots\\
  \langle a_1, a_2 \rangle + \langle a_2, a_3 \rangle + \cdots + \langle a_{n-1}, a_n \rangle &= 0\end{array}$$

where $\langle a, b \rangle := a^H b$. How can one find $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$ that satisfy these equations?

Comment: Is this a question of math research (which is the kind of question this MO website is for)?

Comment: Simulposted to m.se, with no notice to either site, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2552089/a-vector-equation-set-about-inner-product Please don't do that.

Comment: Simultaneously posting without a cross-reference is, indeed, a misdemeanor (though, perhaps, the first offense should be forgivable). As to the question itself, it is stated not too badly except that some normalization is necessary (otherwise "Put all $a_k=0$" is an answer) and I **don't** see why it is trivial off hand. How about you, @GerryMyerson? (or any other one who voted to close). .